# Potential iOS memory leak with CFUUIDBytes

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I have a static method defined as follows:

```
+(NSString*)getNewIdAsBase64
{
    // Grab new uuid
    CFUUIDRef originalUuid = CFUUIDCreate(nil);//create a new UUID
    //NSLog(@"Step a: original uuidObj = %@",originalUuid);
    CFUUIDBytes originalBytes = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes (originalUuid);//ISSUE

    NSData* data88  = [NSData dataWithBytes: &originalBytes length: sizeof(originalBytes)];
    NSString* hugo = [data88 base64EncodedString];

    return hugo;

}
```

When I run Product->Analyze on my project then the line commented with //ISSUE raises the following issue:

```
Potential leak of an object alocated on line 23 and stored into 'originalUuid'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to release the object you create even if you are using ARC:

```
+(NSString*)getNewIdAsBase64
{
    // Grab new uuid
    CFUUIDRef originalUuid = CFUUIDCreate(nil);//create a new UUID
    //NSLog(@"Step a: original uuidObj = %@",originalUuid);
    CFUUIDBytes originalBytes = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes (originalUuid);//ISSUE

    NSData* data88  = [NSData dataWithBytes: &originalBytes length: sizeof(originalBytes)];
    NSString* hugo = [data88 base64EncodedString];

    CFRelease(originalUuid);
    return hugo;

}
```